# VBA: Add row values until they are greater than or equal to X

Tags: excel, vba

I haven't been able to find anything on this so sorry if it has been asked before. *Edited*

I have a number of dates and times that are listed in a column and they have varying hours between them. 
Starting from the bottom (earliest date) I am looking to identify the next row that is over 24 hours away and have that value display under "Next Time over 24 Hrs." Sample provided.

```
+------------+-------+--+-----------------------+-------+
| Date       | Time  |  | Next Time over 24 Hrs |       |
+------------+-------+--+-----------------------+-------+
| 04/15/2018 | 16:09 |  | None                  | None  |
+------------+-------+--+-----------------------+-------+
| 04/15/2018 | 12:11 |  | None                  | None  |
+------------+-------+--+-----------------------+-------+
| 04/15/2018 | 06:10 |  | None                  | None  |
+------------+-------+--+-----------------------+-------+
| 04/14/2018 | 14:24 |  | 04/15/2018            | 16:09 |
+------------+-------+--+-----------------------+-------+
| 04/14/2018 | 06:10 |  | 04/15/2018            | 06:10 |
+------------+-------+--+-----------------------+-------+
| 04/13/2018 | 07:31 |  | 04/14/2018            | 14:24 |
+------------+-------+--+-----------------------+-------+
| 04/13/2018 | 07:31 |  | 04/14/2018            | 14:24 |
+------------+-------+--+-----------------------+-------+
| 04/13/2018 | 06:39 |  | 04/14/2018            | 14:24 |
+------------+-------+--+-----------------------+-------+
| 04/13/2018 | 06:10 |  | 04/14/2018            | 06:10 |
+------------+-------+--+-----------------------+-------+
```

*Update: Final code used here

```
Sub test()

Dim x As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim xTime As Double
Dim iTime As Double
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

         For x = LastRow + 1 To 2 Step -1
          If Cells(x, "F") = "VALUE" Then
            xTime = Cells(x, "A").Value + Cells(x, "B").Value
            For i = x To 2 Step -1
                iTime = Cells(i, "A").Value + Cells(i, "B").Value
                If iTime - xTime = 1 Or iTime - xTime > 1 Then
                    Cells(x, "R").Value = Cells(i, "A").Value
                    Cells(x, "S").Value = Cells(i, "B").Value
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next I
          End If
        Next x


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. If I understood your request correctly, this should do the trick.

```
Option Explicit
Sub time()

Dim x As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim xTime As Double
Dim iTime As Double
Dim LastRow As Long

'adjust worksheet and table names accordingly to mach yours
LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Table1").Rows.Count

    For x = LastRow + 1 To 2 Step -1
        xTime = Cells(x, "A").Value + Cells(x, "B").Value
        For i = x To 2 Step -1
            iTime = Cells(i, "A").Value + Cells(i, "B").Value
            If iTime - xTime = 1 Or iTime - xTime > 1 Then
                Cells(x, "C").Value = Cells(i, "A").Value
                Cells(x, "D").Value = Cells(i, "B").Value
                Exit For
            End If
            Next i
        Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Is there a way to make this so that it only does it for specific rows?

Comment: In my opinion, more or less everything possible, but sometimes it is to difficult to achieve and not worth the trouble. But to adjust this code to exclude some rows should not be to hard. Specify what do you mean by saying "specific"? Which rows should be excluded?

Answer (score 1):

For a formula only approach and using an extra column:

With your `Date and Time` table going from `A1:B10`.

- Add this formula to `C2` and drag down to `C10`:
  `=SUM($A2,$B2)`
- Add this formula to `D2` and drag down to `D10`:
  `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A2,MATCH($C2+1,$C$2:$C2,-1)),"")`
- Add this to `E2` and drag down:
  `=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B2,MATCH($C2+1,$C$2:$C2,-1)),"")`

If your date column contains the date & time but is formatted to show just the date then you can change references to column `C` to column `A`.

```
| Date       | Time  | Hidden           | Next Time over 24 Hrs                                 |                                                       |
|------------|-------|------------------|-------------------------------------------------------|-------------------------------------------------------|
| 15/04/2018 | 16:09 | =SUM($A2,$B2)    | =IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A2,MATCH($C2+1,$C$2:$C2,-1)),"") | =IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B2,MATCH($C2+1,$C$2:$C2,-1)),"") |
| 15/04/2018 | 12:11 | 15/04/2018 12:11 |                                                       |                                                       |
| 15/04/2018 | 06:10 | 15/04/2018 06:10 |                                                       |                                                       |
| 14/04/2018 | 14:24 | 14/04/2018 14:24 |                                                       |                                                       |
| 14/04/2018 | 06:10 | 14/04/2018 06:10 | 15/04/2018                                            | 06:10                                                 |
| 13/04/2018 | 07:31 | 13/04/2018 07:31 | 14/04/2018                                            | 14:24                                                 |
| 13/04/2018 | 07:31 | 13/04/2018 07:31 | 14/04/2018                                            | 14:24                                                 |
| 13/04/2018 | 06:39 | 13/04/2018 06:39 | 14/04/2018                                            | 14:24                                                 |
| 13/04/2018 | 06:10 | 13/04/2018 06:10 | 14/04/2018                                            | 06:10                                                 |
```